# NoClassDefFoundError Java

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am writing a program for a class.  When I compile it it returns an *Possible loss of precision* error.  I was told that this error shouldn't matter.  However, a [filename].class file wasn't made.  So, when I run my program it returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Code
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Code
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Code.  Program will exit.
```

How do I fix this error to where I can run it?  The code follows.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Code {

    //Constructor
    public Code() {} //Code constructor

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        Code coder = new Code();

        String message = "Hello";
        byte[] codebook = new byte[] {
            1, 43, 31, 78, 0
        };

        coder.crypt(message, codebook);

    } //main

    public String crypt(String message, byte[] codebook) {

        int lcv = 0;
        byte[] altered = message.getBytes(); //message in sequence of bytes

        System.out.println("Original Message > " + message);


        while (lcv <= altered.length) { //encoding

            altered[lcv] = altered[lcv] ^ codebook[lcv]; //XOR on the original message with the codebook

            lcv++;

        } //while

        return new String(altered, "UTF-8"); //decode

    } //crypt

} //Code
```

Would this potentially be caused by this?

```
    Code.java:33: possible loss of precision
    found   : int
    required: byte
       altered[lcv] = altered[lcv] ^ codebook[lcv];//XOR on the original message with the codebook
                                ^
    1 error
```

Comment: using eclipse??? or running it from command prompt?

Comment: Running it from a Linux based command prompt

Answer (score 0):

first thing is you need to have your .class file generated and ready to be run

second if you are running it from command prompt and your class path is not set, java will not be able to find your class file

so in that case set class path like

```
SET CLASS_PATH=<path_to_your_class_file_dir>
```

Comment: I have tried to do this; however, the system I am using does not support SET.

Comment: @jwilliams17349 then tell us what OS you are using

Comment: Linux version 3.2.0-58-virtual (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #88-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: export CLASSPATH=<path>

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can run out side an ide.

I am hoping you get this error when you are running out side IDE

You can run your program in couple of different ways

1. **java -classpath [path where your class file is] Code**
2. Or you can export from eclipse as a runnable jar file. 
   in that case you can run it as 
   **java -jar [jar name]**

**To create the .class file use**
javac Code.java

I hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've compiled the java program first - if you don't compile it, you will get this error. on the command prompt, `javac Code.java` then try running it.

edit: right, not sure how I missed that. anyhow - a couple of things. Crypt needs a catch for unsupportedEncodingException

`public String crypt(String message, byte[] codebook) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {`

you've also got an int in your byte array. you can cast lcv to a byte if you want, but its going to cause problems if you dont account for it.

`altered[lcv] = (byte) (altered[lcv] ^ codebook[lcv]);`

once that's fixed, you'll get an out of bounds exception at index 5 for your array. It isn't properly compiling due to these problems. You'll need to set the comparison to `while (lcv < altered.length)` rather than `<=`

Comment: I do try to compile it, as stated in the original question.